# How to speed up a really long for loop?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, amazon-s3, multiprocessing

I'm trying to iterate over all the objects in all the AWS account S3 buckets(it starts on line 4). It then checks all objects ACLs for public access.

```
def check_object_acl(bucket_name):
    try:
        s3bucket = s3resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
        for key in s3bucket.objects.all():
            response = s3client.get_object_acl(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key.key)
            logger.info('Object: {}, ACL: {}'.format(key.key, response['Grants']))
            for grant in response['Grants']:
                for (key, value) in grant.items():
                    if key == 'Permission' and any(permission in value for permission in permissions_to_check):
                        for (grantee_key, grantee_value) in grant['Grantee'].items():
                            if 'URI' in grantee_key and grant['Grantee']['URI'] in public_acl_indicator:
                                if bucket_name not in public_buckets:
                                    public_buckets.append(bucket_name)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        logger.info("{}, BucketName: {}".format(error, bucket_name))
        logger.info(" ")
        pass
```

The problem is:

Some buckets have no objects at all, others have ~5, but a few of them have 10k, 50k, 80k, and even 200k objects.

For a bucket with around 1k objects it took almost 40 minutes to finish...

How can I **speed up** all this process considering that I only have **2 physical cores**?

Comment: Really, you can't  All of those `s3` calls involve network exchanges.  You just can't do this kind of processing on s3 storage on a regular basis.  Special cases, sure, but not every day.

Comment: You might want to consider using [S3 Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html). This can be configured to override any object-level permissions, so you can at least 'skip over' any buckets with this configured.

Comment: "only have 2 physical cores" .. you could still use mutliprocessing.  As Tim mentioned, much of the time will be spent waiting for network responses, so even 2 cores can still handle a few worker threads each.  That said, I'd be hard pressed to imagine getting more than a 5-10x speed up in practice.

Comment: I agree. I think the best solution is what John suggested. Only scan the buckets that don't pass the BlockAcessConfiguration test.